# What's the law on the NHS's postcode lottery?

Tags: england-and-wales, medical

Googling yielded a 2002 editorial [*Impact of the European Convention on Human Rights on medical law*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/pmj.78.924.573), but this may be outdated. Has anyone tried to sue the NHS on the ground that their postcode lottery violates e.g. Article 14 of the ECHR?

> The enjoyment of the rights and freedoms set forth in this European Convention on Human Rights shall be secured without discrimination on any ground such as sex, race, colour, language, religion, political or other opinion, national or social origin, association with a national minority, property, birth or other status.

I suspect someone must've tried to sue or judicially review the NHS, because they feel that this postcode lottery is illegally discriminatory, and because the postcode lottery ["is alive and well still."](https://mtg.org.uk/the-nhs-postcode-lottery-alive-and-well-still/)

> Firstly, the extent of the variation was astonishing. For example, less than one patient per 100,000 population in Southampton was referred for a computed tomography colonoscopy (a vital procedure for diagnosing and ruling out bowel cancer) compared with 59 patients per 100,000 in neighbouring Fareham and Gosport. Meanwhile, eight out of ten patients were admitted to a stroke unit within the recommended four hours of arrival at hospital in Hillingdon, compared to two out of ten in Wyre Forest.
>
> Secondly, a distinct north-south divide emerged, with nine out of ten of the poorest performing CCGs located in the south of England.

#### Factual Background

[Q&A: Postcode lottery | NHS | The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2000/nov/09/NHS)

> **What is the postcode lottery?**
> The postcode lottery is shorthand for seemingly random countrywide variations in the provision and quality of public services - the huge gap between the best and the rest. Where you live defines the standard of services you can expect. So if you live in the "wrong" area, and, in extreme cases, on the "wrong" side of a road, you may get a poorer service than your neighbour or you may not get the service at all and have to pay for it privately. The postcode lottery is a big issue in the [NHS](https://www.theguardian.com/society/nhs), where the gap between the rhetoric of a comprehensive and universal "national" service and the reality is increasingly stretched.

[Addressing the ‘postcode lottery’ in local resource allocation decisions: a framework for clinical commissioning groups](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3618168/)

> The NHS Constitution emphasizes patients’ rights to expect these decisions to be made ‘rationally’.<sup>[1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3618168/#JRS479192C1)</sup>

[NHS postcode lottery persists for most vulnerable patients – Which? News](https://www.which.co.uk/news/2019/07/nhs-postcode-lottery-persists-for-most-vulnerable-patients/)

> See below for the best and worst Clinical Commissioning Groups (CCGs) on continuing healthcare across England.

> [image]

Comment: This question could be improved by showing which of the articles of the European Convention on Human Rights are being infringed.  It is not obvious that any cover the activities of the NHS.

Comment: @Dave I quoted Article 14 above?